# Why degeneracy increases with energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics

So suppose I have a bunch of particles interacting among themselves with a potential function that is arbitary (not defined).

The total potential energy of the system is the sum of individual interactions.

How can it be possible that as the potential enrgy of the total system increase the number of degeneracy also increases?

Its related to boltzmann distribution. $G(U)e^{-\frac{U}{KT}}$. Here $G$ is the density of states. How can I be sure that the density of states is increasing if I dont know about the functional form of the interaction potential?

Comment: *G(w)e^-(U/KT). Here g…* You wrote $G$, not $g$. What is $w$? The $K$ should be $k$.

Comment: There are more ways to add up to a big number than a small number.